# Terms and conditions of using RSS feed content

Tags: web-applications, rss, feed

I want to use the RSS feeds from several sites. I wanna know the terms and conditions of using the content from RSS feeds.

Is it possible to copy the RSS content from the feed url and put it in my site with refrence links to the feed provider..?

Answer (score 2):

There is no umbrella license attached to the RSS technology, it is solely at the discretion of the content provider.

Generally, an RSS feed (that is not restricted behind a login page or similar mechanism) is considered public content, free to copy and redistribute. However, this may not always be the case, and if in any doubt you should contact the Website administrators and ask them under what terms you may use their feed.

Answer (score 0):

Contact the feed providers to ask permission, and/or read their terms and conditions.

Look for copyright disclaimers in the feed itself, as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the site owner. In doubt, ask them.